# Is there a way to use mouse events as touch events on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to use this Javascripts functionality as a touch event for touch screen devices as well?

```
var down = false;
var scrollLeft = 0;
var x = 0;

var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline');

timeline.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    down = true;
    scrollLeft = this.scrollLeft;
    x = e.clientX; 
});

timeline.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    down = false;
});

timeline.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(down) {
        this.scrollLeft = scrollLeft + x - e.clientX;
    }
});

timeline.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    down = false;
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/AdMFu/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the following:

-`touchstart`

•Action: fires when the screen is touched (will fire for multi-point touches as well)

•Equivalent: `mousedown`

-`touchend`

•Action: fires when a finger is lifted from a screen

•Equivalent: `mouseup`

-`touchmove`

•Action: fires when one or more fingers move on the screen

•Equivalent: `mousemove`

-`touchcancel`

•Action: when a touch event is canceled by the system

•Equivalent: `mouseleave`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdMFu/11/)

Comment: I have tried this on a touch screen device and it does not work :/

Comment: Make sure you prevent default on all event listeners.

Comment: I have done and it still does not seem to work. I've tried it on an emulation and on my mobile device and it still won't scroll.

Answer (score 3):

For IE mobile you use the [Microsoft pointer system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You just change `mousedown` to `MSPointerDown` (watch the caps!). It is exacly the same for the other events. Be aware of multi touch... Microsoft uses pointerID's, so that you can identify every pointer/mouse/finger. How this works, is on a touch event the eventListener always returns an `event.pointerId`. So if you put two fingers down, the `MSPointerDown` event is fired twice, with unique ID's. If you move finger 1, it will return the same ID as at the `MSPointerDown` event, so you can track every point.

Of course you don't want errors, so there is a simple way to check if MSPointer events are supported: `window.navigator.msPointerEnabled`.

**EDIT:**

I would like to add that there is no `e.preventDefault()` for this. Instead you use this css declaration: `-ms-touch-action:none;`. This routes all touch input to your handler, instead of zooming/navigating over the page.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox have JS touch events but others (IE,Opera) do not.

[MDN touch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events#Example)

You will have to use other library (like JQuery Mobile) to handle the touch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery plugin called [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/),so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

It supports all major browser including IE, you can check the complete compatibility list [here](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Compatibility).

Using hammer.js you can simply bind event listeners using the `on` function. The sample code will look something like this.

```
Hammer(el).on("swipeleft", function() {
    alert('you swiped left!');
});
```

you can see all the eventlistener's example on [here](http://rawgithub.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/master/examples/events.html)

Comment: That would be ideal but this is a pure javascript project. It's focusing on reducing load times etc. Thanks though